# How many administrators can Google Analytics add?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to open my Google Analytics to many students.
How many accounts can I add as Google Analytics administrator in free version?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered this type of problem even in large account, there should be no specified limits. The documentation doesn't mention it, so I'd say that should be no specified limits. Certainly more than the number of students in a class.

Answer (score 0):

1 Google Account can consist of 25 Google Analytics accounts

Comment: I think the answer is how many users can be added to see a Google Analytics account. Anyway Google analytics account limit for each Google Account raised from 25 to 100.